# Replace a variable value in a dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring

I'm wondering if is it possible to replace a variable value in a Grafana's dashboard and show more readable labels

I have this variable:

[image]

And i'd like to replace those values in the dashboard to show more descriptive titles

[image]

¿Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Adding $serviceId to the row title does bring that value dashboard/row name? So am also confused as to what you want to do?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#add-a-custom-variable) where it explains key/value pairs